# How to set register value to enable interrupt?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am handling interrupt for a device in Android. (Android 4.2.2 Kernel 2.6.29, running on Mach-Goldfish virtual device).

So far I have registered my device with the interrupt #17. It hasn't been enabled yet so signals sent to this interrupt are ignored and my interrupt handler is not notified.

The register that enables my device is at offset 0x00, and the memory address, as returned by

`(char __iomem *)IO_ADDRESS(resource->start - IO_START)`

starts at 0xFE016000.

I tried: (in `mydevice_probe()`)

```
writel(0x07, 0xFE016000);
//0x07 is a mask to enable three sub-devices at bit 0, bit 1 and bit 2.
```

But the kernel crashed right away. The following `writel`s also did not work:

```
writel(0x00, 0xFE016000);
writel(0x01, 0xFE016000);
```

What did I miss? Could any one show me how to get this done? In case I got the start address wrong, could you point out the way to get it correctly?

Thanks.

P/S: The kernel panic:

```
qemu: fatal: mydevice_write: Bad offset fea000

R00=c02ef00b R01=00000000 R02=00000007 R03=e0808000
R04=c0340864 R05=c031e3b0 R06=c0173b6c R07=c031e3cc
R08=00000000 R09=00100100 R10=00000000 R11=df827e34
R12=ff016000 R13=df827e18 R14=c002e96c R15=c0030aac
PSR=20000013 --C- A svc32
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: @Mellowcandle it's a sensor.

Comment: By which device I meant which board is it?

Comment: @Mellowcandle It's one of the Android's virtual device, Mach-goldfish.

Comment: Which Android version, which kernel version ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle Android 4.2.2 Kernel 2.6.29

Comment: How did you get the `0xFE016000` address? I'm going to take a wild guess that you're using a physical address instead of a virtual one. In that case, you'll want to either feed that into `ioremap()` to get a virtual address to use with `writel()`.

Comment: You might want to add the first few lines of the kernel panic into your question.

Comment: @tangrs 0xFE16000 was returned by `(char __iomem *)IO_ADDRESS(resource->start - IO_START)`. I'm running on ARM so there's no need to use ioremap(), I think so. Correct me if I'm wrong :D

Comment: What's the definition of the `IO_ADDRESS` macro? Edit: Is the address in `resource->start` statically mapped? A search on LXR just turns up a few macros defined by various machines that use it to access static mappings.

Comment: @tangrs it is defined in hardware.h as:
`#define IO_ADDRESS(x) ((x) + IO_BASE)`. While IO_BASE = 0xfe000000 and IO_START = 0xff000000

Comment: That looks like a static mapping. Are you sure that `resource->start` contains an address that is in the static mapping? Look for an array of type `struct map_desc *` in your machine folder. Check if the address is in one of the descriptions.

Comment: Or better yet, just use `ioremap()`. I.e `void __iomem *io_base = ioremap(resource->start, resource->end - resource->start + 1);` then use `writel(value, io_base + offset);`

Comment: @tangrs Yes all addresses are definitely static mapped. I tried your code, still crash :((. And more over, it crashed and complained that there is a "fatal error: bad offset fea000" at `mydevice_write`, or sometime `mydevice_read`, while I put the code in mydevice_probe and I don't even have two function mydevice_write and mydevice_read... This seems more and more bizarre to me... Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you include the top few lines of the kernel panic in your question? It's a bit hard to tell what's going on

Comment: Note that [Goldfish](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/platform/goldfish) is an Android emulator on the `x86` unless I am mistaken.  How do you map a sensor **device** on a virtual platform?  Problem behind keyboard?

Comment: @artlessnoise Goldfish runs on x86 but it emulates ARM. The sensor is memory-mapped with several register in the goldfish board, which I don't get access to. I only know which register does what and my first attempt is to enable the interrupt, given at offset 0x00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to close my question.
it turns out that the emulator is faulty.
Normally `writel(MASK, IO_ADDRESS(resource->start - IO_START));` should work.